# std::function and dynamic library unload

Tags: c++, c++11

If I create a std::function that contains a function in a library that I have dynamically loaded what should the behavior be if I first dynamically unload the library then let the std::function destructor run.

I ask as I have seen different behaviors on different platforms, running the destructor with no problems, throwing and exception and terminating. I'm not a fan of undefined behavior where it seems easily avoidable as in this case.

So are there strong reasons to favour one behaviour over another? Has anyone heard any discussion on this topic? I know the standard doesn't talk about dynamic loading much although there are a few papers such as http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2407.html but they don't really address this issue.

Comment: Can you show (a minimal example of) the code that crashes on some platforms? `std::function`'s destructor shouldn't call the function, so I see no problem.

Comment: Is it possible that the `std::function` has some object(s) attached to it, which in turn has a destructor in the shared library? As Brian says, I don't see how the destructor of the `std::function` itself could cause a problem, but some stuff that is bound to the `std::function`, could be a problem.